# I got a way worse grade than my classmates for equal performance. What should I do?

Tags: grades, coursework

The professor for this course was, according to every one of my classmates (only 7 of us total so I could get all the opinions) a nightmare. To illustrate, in the last week of class, after we present a final assignment (no instructions other than the title of the assignment in the syllabus), he asks us if we'd been getting any of his emails for the whole semester. We said no. That last class was a sizable part of the grade but obviously no one had instructions or any knowledge of the percentage of the assignment relative to our grade.

Each week people in our course were confused about material and procedure and we all thought we were fools that should have known better. But we all had realized, in this last class meeting, that there was a reason for the disconnect: the instructions were not going through to us via email.

There was a discrepancy in my grade vs the other classmates grades, even though there is no discernible performance gap. I got the lower grade. The classmates I spoke with were surprised, for the same reason I am - namely they did not perceive a noticeable performance gap. My skin is crawling at the thought of asking the professor what the reason for this low grade was, but should I do it? Or can I go elsewhere (i.e. a Dean or something) first? I know for a fact other students are willing to attest to this professors disorganization and other bad qualities (some already have). I also suspect this professor has had complaints lodged against him in the past for similar reasons.

Comment: *in my opinion* is the key phrase here. Chanches are, your opinion is not correct.

Comment: I edited for clarity. As I said later though my classmates did agree with me.

Comment: @Jazzie3 quite often what students think is equivalent work, and what actually is equivalent work are different.  I've had students come to me with a friends paper for comparison (math); all of the broad strokes were indeed there, but none of the same detail was.  It's possible that you learn something important by just asking what it is that the prof felt was missing from your work.  Who knows, maybe they missed something as well.

Comment: +1 to Scott H's comment. I'll add that you shouldn't assume the worst. The professor has no reason to want to fail you - "I thought a class in ____ and half the students failed" is not something to be proud of. Ask the professor why you received a low grade. Do it in a non-accusatory way, and odds are they'll be willing to discuss it.

Comment: We've all had a bad grade that we didn't expect. What you need to do is find out why you were given one and not accuse anybody of doing wrong by you. For example, I got an average mark on an assignment I thought was pretty decent. When I approached my marker about it, they said "The assignment was actually well written, but due to the marking criteria there were several things that were missing from it so I had to deduct marks."

Comment: As to the comment about the professor not wanting to give bad grades: I sensed a good deal of animus. On my last day this professor made a snarky comment to me and a classmate about how long this semester had seemed. Sure I can't read into this too much and some will say it's subjective, but again, taken together with the prof's lack of responsibility mentioned above, I would say that he was objectively toxic. Also, another student had _already_ complained to the school about him, so perhaps he was feeling even more upset - I'm not sure if he knew about the complaint before grades were due.

Comment: @Jazzie3 Remarking that it seemed like a long semester doesn't sound snarky to me.  It sounds like how I and pretty nearly every instructor I know feels by the end of every semester.  Teaching is a lot more work than you may think!

Comment: I am aware that teaching requires a lot of work - I taught high schoolers. Also - context matters. you can read the words "piss off" and not know whether it was in jest or serious based on context, right? I was trying to provide context about this person: the professor went the entire semester without knowing if his emails were reaching us, which suggests irresponsibility. Another student was compelled to complain _before the end of the semester_. This is not a put together person, like many of you may be. I understand professors sympathy toward their own but there are bad apples, you know.

Comment: @Jazzie3 Okay, how is it possible your whole class went the entire semester not knowing what the assignments were because you weren't getting email?  No one went to your instructor's office hours and said, "I don't understand this assignment", and the instructor didn't ask if they'd read the email and wasn't told they hadn't seen any email?  You make it sound like it's all the instructor's fault but there are too many loose ends in your story.

Answer (score 12):

Easy answer:  Go talk to your professor at office hours.  You should escalate to your department chair or the dean only after you've tried in good faith and failed to resolve the problem directly with your instructor.  Don't escalate unless it's genuinely serious.

Try to be open-minded toward the possibility that there were deficiencies in your work that you may not have spotted that explain why your grade was lower than you think it should be.  Your fellow students' opinions are not reliable indicators of anything nor is it helpful to cite their complaints or opinions as justification for yours.  Go with the expectation you will learn something, not with the sole goal of getting more points.